# Teleportation and the observers effect

Tags: observers, quantum-teleportation

I'm a layman, and I was wondering, if teleportation is to ever exist, I'd assume it'd be in the sense that you would take the object you are trying to teleport, get it's exact makeup, then send that information to another location for it to be rebuilt, essentially destroying the original and creating an exact clone in another location.

If this is the case, then wouldn't this be technically impossible due to the observers effect, as observing the object would affect it therefore making creating an exact (or very very similar) clone be impossible?

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question. But according to quantum mechanics it is *possible* although difficult. By careful tricks and procedures this can be done but the original being would be destroyed. And so I recommend you watch these videos which explains this( especially video 3):

[Quantum Teleportation](https://youtu.be/DxQK1WDYI_k)

[Cloning](https://youtu.be/owPC60Ue0BE)

[How Teleportation works](https://youtu.be/dAaHHGHuy1c)